# SQL query searching for a value in two columns and gets the value from the other column and its count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

There are two columns in the table: **`COL_LEFT`** and **`COL_RIGHT`**.

I need to select all rows where value of **`FOO`** occurs in either of these two columns and generate two columns:

1. Column with the other value that is on the same row with **`FOO`** ie value from the other column (**`COL_LEFT`** or **`COL_RIGHT`**)
2. Column with a number of occurences of that other value

I am guessing there would be GROUP BY in the query but I am not sure how to construct the whole query.

I am using SQL Server LocalDB database.

Here is the example of how it should work:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you add sample data as DDL+DML (create table + insert into table) it makes it much easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be the following.

```sql
SELECT
  v.OPPOSITE,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CASE WHEN t.COL_LEFT = 'FOO' THEN t.COL_RIGHT ELSE t.COL_LEFT END
)) v(OPPOSITE)
WHERE 'FOO' IN (t.COL_LEFT, t.COL_RIGHT)
GROUP BY
  v.OPPOSITE;
```

But I think the most efficient solution would either of the following two:

```sql
SELECT
  t.OPPOSITE,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.COL_RIGHT AS OPPOSITE
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.COL_LEFT = 'FOO'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.COL_LEFT
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.COL_RIGHT = 'FOO'
) t
GROUP BY
  t.OPPOSITE;
```

```sql
SELECT
  t.OPPOSITE,
  SUM(t.COUNT) AS COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.COL_RIGHT AS OPPOSITE,
      COUNT(*) AS COUNT
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.COL_LEFT = 'FOO'
    GROUP BY
      t.COL_RIGHT

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.COL_LEFT,
      COUNT(*)
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.COL_RIGHT = 'FOO'
    GROUP BY
      t.COL_LEFT
) t
GROUP BY
  t.OPPOSITE;
```

This would need two separate indexes, with the columns in opposite order, to be performant.

```sql
(COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT)
(COL_RIGHT, COL_LEFT)
```

As you can see from [**this fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60b64afbc82fe0a5d77e5dd82211c10e), the second and third execution plans have no sorts or hash matches, whereas the first requires a sort.

Comment: Nice answer, provide different approaches and also cover explanation for the execution plan. A good source for learning!

Comment: There is actually an even simpler solution that still has no sort, see edit

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you guys!! I really appreciate this. All of these solutions are very useful. The query that is most comprehensible for me is probably the one by Young Shun. But supposing your solution is more efficient I guess I will choose yours. Btw. you were faster than I could even study each solution and run a test. Again thank you very much.

Comment: The other answer is essentially the same as my first option, it will compile to the same query plan

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that you can do with:

1. Filter records with `[LEFT]` or `[RIGHT]` is 'Foo'.
2. Place the value which is not 'Foo' in `[LEFT]` column.
3. Group by `[LEFT]` column and count.

```
WITH CTX AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN [LEFT] = 'Foo' THEN [RIGHT] ELSE [LEFT] END AS [LEFT]
    FROM Ori
    WHERE [LEFT] = 'Foo'
    OR [RIGHT] = 'Foo'
)
SELECT [LEFT], COUNT(*) AS [COUNT]
FROM CTX
GROUP BY [LEFT]
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d199/4/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You forgot to add "FROM my_table" before WHERE in the first SELECTION. With that it appears to work. You have that right in Fiddle link though.

Comment: You're welcome, And thanks for the reminder, accidentally remove the FROM part when removing the second column which is not required. Updated the answer, thanks again!